Notation probability theory $(x,y) \sim D$
Hey I just have a question about the notation in probability theory.
The $(x,y) \sim D$ notation is often used, for example for the risk:

$R(h) = \mathbb{E}_{(x,y) \sim D} [L(h_{\theta}(x), y)]$

I am usually also taking this notation, but i am really not sure how to use in a case like the following:

Is there a standard way how to do it? Thanks for the help!

What notation are you asking about? $\mathbb{E}_X[\ldots]$ or...?

I just mean the subscript notation: $\mathbb{E}{(x,y) \sim D}$ vs $\mathbb{E}{XY}$
